# Formalising "every number other than $0$ has a unique multiplicative inverse"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

The domain is the set of all real numbers.

> Express "Every number other than 0 has a unique multiplicative inverse" as a logical expression.

My solution is: `∀x ∃y ∀z (((x ≠ 0) → ((xy = 1) ∧ ((z ≠ y) → (xz ≠ 1)))))`.

However, the given solution is: `∀x ∃y ∀z (((x ≠ 0) → (xy = 1)) ∧ ((z ≠ y) → (xz ≠ 1)))`.

Shouldn't we check if the number is unique(`(z ≠ y) → (xz ≠ 1)`) only if `x ≠ 0`?

However, the given solution checks whether the number is unique regardless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to the problem is the safer and more logical option; if you want to make a claim about every number other than $0$, your predicate should have the form $(x \ne 0) \to (\text{everything else})$.

However, the textbook's solution "gets away" with being sloppy, because the statement $$((x \ne 0) \to (xy=1)) \land ((z \ne y) \to (xz \ne 1))$$ is still true when $x=0$. (In that case, the second clause becomes "$(z \ne y) \to (0 \ne 1)$", which is true regardless of $y$ and $z$.)

Intuitively, checking the clause $(z \ne y) \to (xz \ne 1)$ unconditionally means that even if $x = 0$, we still claim that $x$ does not have *multiple* multiplicative inverses. This is a true statement, so the textbook's solution is fine (at least, fine for some purposes).

In a world where $0$ did have multiple multiplicative inverses, your solution would still be correct, but the textbook's solution would not be. So the two logical expressions are not *purely logically* equivalent; they are equivalent under some assumptions about how the real number $0$ works.

Answer (score 1):

$$∀x \:∃y \:∀z\: \Big(  (x ≠ 0 → xy = 1)   ∧    (z ≠ y → xz ≠ 1)    \Big)\tag1$$
$$∀x \:∃y \:∀z\: \Big(   x ≠ 0 →   xy = 1 ∧  (z ≠ y → xz ≠ 1)       \Big)\tag2$$

While both statements are mathematically true, statement $(2)$ is the accurate translation of the given natural-language sentence, whereas statement $(1)$ is a stronger assertion (in fact, it's a [logically](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E6x%7E7y%7E6z((Px%7E5Qxy)%7E1(Rzy%7E5Sxz))%7E5%7E6x%7E7y%7E6z(Px%7E5Qxy%7E1(Rzy%7E5Sxz))) [stronger](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E6x%7E7y%7E6z((Px%7E5Qxy)%7E1(Rzy%7E5Sxz))%7E4%7E6x%7E7y%7E6z(Px%7E5Qxy%7E1(Rzy%7E5Sxz))) assertion) than statement $(2).$